# What are the necessary changes in AGE's source code to create functions to be used with openCypher syntax?

Tags: c, apache-age

I wanted to create a function in AGE's source code so that it can be used with the openCypher syntax. I noticed that there are some commits that add these kinds of functions, such as [#710](https://github.com/apache/age/commit/88c44b9a1845092510abaae5053b01b46ad076e8) which implements the `isEmpty()` predicate function, and also [#146](https://github.com/apache/age/commit/6b89697351aab8806136503d9806026b3cb927db) that adds the `reverse()` function. Both these commits changed the `agtype.c` file to add the definition of the functions there, and the declaration of the `isEmpty()` function is added in `age--1.2.0.sql`, but for the `reverse()` function it is not (at least not in this commit).

The declaration of the `isEmpty()` function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ag_catalog.age_isempty(agtype)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE c
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
PARALLEL SAFE
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME';
```

And it's definition in `agtype.c`:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(age_isempty);
/*
 * Executor function for isEmpty(property).
 */

Datum age_isempty(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    // code goes here...
    
    // at the end:
    PG_RETURN_BOOL(result == 0);
}
```

Although the function is declared as `age_isempty()`, in the `cypher_match.sql` it is called as `isEmpty()`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('for_isEmpty',
 $$CREATE (u:for_pred {id:1, type: "empty", list: [], map: {}, string: ""}),
          (v:for_pred {id:2, type: "filled", list: [1], map: {a:1}, string: "a"}),
          (w:for_pred)$$)
AS (a agtype);

-- Match vertices with empty properties

SELECT * FROM cypher('for_isEmpty',
 $$MATCH (u:for_pred) WHERE isEmpty(u.list) RETURN properties(u) $$) -- here.
AS (u agtype);
```

So, are these the only files that should be changed or is it necessary to change the code in somewhere else? Also, why is the function called as `isEmpty()` and not `age_isempty()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse() function was already present in the AGE code prior to PR #146, so its declaration can be found in the `age.sql` file. Regarding the creation of a new function, you are correct. You need to declare it in the `age.sql` and create a definition in in a related `.c` file, similar to how `reverse` and `isEmpty` are related to string types in AGE.

The reason the function is named `isEmpty`, instead of `age_isEmpty`, is because all functions within a Cypher query in Apache AGE have the prefix `age_` added to their name.

Answer (score 1):

In `transform_FuncCall`, all function names are prefixed with `age_`. This is the reason why calling `isempty` instead of `age_isempty` still works.

```
 // copy in the prefix - all AGE functions are prefixed with age_ 
 strncpy(ag_name, "age_", 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Files that need to be changed when creating a function in AGE includes but not limited to:

- Define the function in `agtype.c`
- Add regression tests

1. `expr.out`
2. `expr.sql`

- Create it in `age--1.3.0.sql`

> Also, why is the function called as isEmpty() and not age_isempty()?
> To answer the above question, `age_isempty()` is utilized outside a cypher query whereas `isEmpty` is used within a cypher query.